# How can add properties to my objects based on the duplicates inside the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects

```
let arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        id:4,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
    },
    {
        id:4,
    }
]
```

i need to find and change every object in the array based on condition.
So if there are duplicates in the array i need to set on my objects `100` except last duplicate where i should have `200`.
If i don't have any duplicates than i should have again `200`

So the output shpuld be

```
let arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        number: 100
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        number: 100
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        number: 200
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        number: 200
    },
    {
        id:4,
        number: 100
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        number: 200
    },
    {
        id:4,
        number: 200
    }
]
```

so `id 1 has duplicates`.
That is why the fiurst occurences are set with `number:100` and the last one i set with `number:200`.

`Id 2` has number 200 because there are no duplicates and it is first occurance in the list.

**what i tried**

I got stuck at

```
for(let item of arr) {
    for(let item2 of arr) {
        if(item.id === item2.id) {
            item.number = 100;
        } else {
            item.number = 200;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the array in reverse and track which `id`s you've seen, here using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set).

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, }, { id: 1, }, { id: 2, }, { id: 1, }, { id: 4, }, { id: 3, }, { id: 4, }]

let i = arr.length;
const seen = new Set();

while (i--) {
  arr[i].number = seen.has(arr[i].id) ? 100 : 200;
  seen.add(arr[i].id)
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.map()` to iterate over your array. I think it can provide a nice and concise solution:

```
const result = arr.map((item, index) => {
  const duplicate = arr.filter((_, indx) => indx > index).some((i) => i.id === item.id);
  return { ...item, number: duplicate ? 100 : 200 }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply achieve it via [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) & [Array.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) methods.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input array
let arr = [{
  id: 1,
}, {
  id: 1,
}, {
  id: 2,
}, {
  id: 1,
}, {
  id:4,
}, {
  id: 3,
}, {
  id:4,
}];

// Getting ID's from each object and create a seperate array
let idArr = arr.map(function(item) { return item.id });

// Iterating through the id's array and assigning number property to an original array as per the requirement.
idArr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (idArr.indexOf(item) === idArr.lastIndexOf(item)) {
    arr[index].number = 200;
  } else {
    arr[index].number = 100;
    arr[idArr.lastIndexOf(item)].number = 200;
  }  
});

// Result
console.log(arr);
```